# Correct way of grouping tests in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am new to TestNG. We are trying to implement POM framework for automation testing. We are using WebDriver, Java, TestNG and TestLink. After executing test cases I am sending result to TestLink.

I have created bunch of test scripts.
Each of my test scripts has many test cases.
Sometimes we might want to run specific tests for specific release. What is the easiest way to manage this? I know we can disable tests in TestNG but I might have to manually go and update many of my test scripts. I feel group functionality in TestNg is not that good. Any suggestions?

Comment: don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem/question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use annotations in your test cases:

i.e.

```
 @Test(groups = { "FUNCTIONAL_TEST_GROUP" })
```

Or

```
   @Test(groups = { "REGRESSION_TEST_GROUP" })
```

**UPDATE**

If you are using Maven to run your tests, you can specify which ones to run from the command line like this:

```
mvn test -Dgroups=FUNCTIONAL_TEST_GROUP,REGRESSION_TEST_GROUP
```

If you are **not** using Maven, you can specify which tests to run in a your `suite.xml` file; like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="TestAll">

  <test name="RegressionTest">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <exclude name="FUNCTIONAL_TEST_GROUP" />
            <include name="REGRESSION_TEST_GROUP" />
        </run>
    </groups>

    <!-- List all tests to include in this suite -->     
    <classes>
        <class name="com.path.to.your.tests" />
    </classes>

    <!-- OR include all packages -->
    <packages>
        <package name=".*" ></package>   
    </packages>

  </test>

</suite>
```

Comment: Thanks ochi. Are you guys able to run large number of tests using this? I get error when I tried this - Node not found. I tried to execute one group from one package. Like in testing.xml I gave instructions to execute all tests which belong to this particular group ABC from the package XYZ.

Comment: Are you using maven? if so, you can try `mvn test -Dgroups=FUNCTIONAL_TEST_GROUP, REGRESSION_TEST_GROUP`

Comment: Yeah doing we will be using Maven in our project. I didn't know that using Maven it will be easy. I will create a sample maven project and try this out.  One more question. In yet above testng.xml can I add package in stead of classes?

Comment: Sure can, just add this `<packages>
   <package name=".*" ></package>   
  </packages>` (updated my answer as well)

Comment: Thanks. Ochi. I get this TestNG error - Node not found. Do you have any idea how can I resolve it?

Comment: Not enough details to be able to tell.  Can you post a new question? add more details about your setup, how you are running it, etc and then let's see if we can help you with that one.   Also read the [ask] page to help you come up with a good question and get awesome answers

Answer (score 2):

My team uses groups kind of like 'tags', since you can add more than one group per test.  This allows you to put different pivots on your tests.

For example, given a simple login test can have something like:

```
@Test(groups = {"login", "basic", "acceptance"}
```

In this way, you can associate this test for anytime someone changes the login code and for whenever you do your basic test suite run but also include it in the larger 'acceptance' suite.

Comment: Thanks doing. Are you guys able to run large number of tests using this? I get error when I tried this - Node not found. I tried to execute one group from one package. Like in testing.xml I gave instructions to execute all tests which belong to this particular group ABC from the package  XYZ.

Comment: How are you executing the tests?  Are you using maven?  What's the commandline like?

Comment: Yeah doing we will be using Maven in our project. I didn't know that using Maven it will be easy. I will create a sample maven project and try this out. I have very less knowledge of Maven at this point so I am not sure what you are asking. I wrote testng.xml and I m running it.

Comment: Yeah you can do it with the testng.xml way or you can do it through commandline (see http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html).  In the example above, you could do something like `mvn test -Dgroups=login` if you want to run all the login groups test, or `mvn test -Dgroups=login,basic' to run tests on both groups.  It will automatically select the unique tests in the groups so you don't have to worry about duplicating test cases when combining groups